# pandas dataframe condition based on regex expression

Tags: python, pandas

```
   TTT
1. 802010001-999-00000285-888-
2. 256788
3. 1940
4. NaN
5. NaN
6. 702010001-X-2YZ-00000285-888-
```

I want to Fill column GGT column with all other values except for the amounts

Required table would be like this

```
   TTT                                GGT
1. 802010001-999-00000285-888-        802010001-999-00000285-888-
2. 256788                             NaN
3. 1940                               NaN
4. NaN                                NaN
5. NaN                                NaN
6. 702010001-X-2YZ-00000285-888-      702010001-X-2YZ-00000285-888-
```

the orginal table has more than 200thousands rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the rows with only numbers, you can use the `match()` method of the string elements of the column TTT. You can use a code like that :

```
df["GGT"] = df["TTT"][df["TTT"].str.match(r'^(\d)+$')==False]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['GGT'] = df['TTT'].mask(pd.to_numeric(df['TTT'], errors='coerce').notna())
```

Or:

```
df['GGT'] = df['TTT'].mask(df["TTT"].astype(str).str.contains('^\d+$', na=True))
print (df)
                             TTT                            GGT
0    802010001-999-00000285-888-    802010001-999-00000285-888-
1                         256788                            NaN
2                           1940                            NaN
3                            NaN                            NaN
4  702010001-X-2YZ-00000285-888-  702010001-X-2YZ-00000285-888-

I
```